# How to find the minimum age from birthday column, but the select only those that are 3 years older than minimum

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table, PATIENT, that has birth dates. I need to run a query that returns only those patients that are 3 years older than the youngest.

I am trying to find a good intro tutorial on nested sql statements because my online class is terrible.

This is as far as I've got:

```
SELECT Phone, Birthday
FROM PATIENT
WHERE Birthday >(
SELECT *
FROM PATIENT
GROUP BY Birthday
ORDER BY Birthday DESC
SELECT MIN(Birthday) AS MinAges
FROM PATIENT);
```

Comment: I only answered because it looked like you gave a solid effort, but this does look like homework. https://sqlzoo.net/ is a good resource for interactive tutorials and it will cover this material well.

Comment: Thanks  for the website! I am struggling with homework and wanted to know a better place to learn the basics than my garbage class, haha.

Comment: How do you define "three years older"?  This is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: If I'm understanding the goal correctly, I need it to identify the minimum age based on birth date, then only return those that are three years older than that. Looking at the table, the youngest person has a birth date of 4/9/2008. So I need any birth dates that are 2005 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Don't google for "nested" that is a different thing. Google "subqueries".

```
SELECT Phone, Birthday
  FROM PATIENT
 WHERE Birthday - 2 > (
           SELECT MIN(Birthday)
             FROM PATIENT
           );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was wondering, what does the "Birthday - 2 >" mean?

Comment: Oops. Wasn't even paying attention. I read it as age and figured it was an integer. Use DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Birthday) >.

Answer (score 0):

Here we select those two fields from patient where the birthday is greater then a nested select where we take the least recent birthday and add 3 years to it. Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

```
SELECT Phone, Birthday
FROM PATIENT
WHERE Birthday >(
SELECT DateAdd(yy, 3, Cast(MIN(Birthday) As datetime))
FROM PATIENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 3 years older you mean that you want the years of the birthday have a difference of 3 then you can use the [`DateAdd()`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/add-to-or-subtract-from-date-and-time-values-9b4d1adc-d54f-4dbb-a759-79b17dcd0df1) function:

```
select phone, birthday from patient
where year(DateAdd('yyyy', -3, birthday)) = (
  select year(min(birthday))
  from patient
)
```

or

```
select phone, birthday from patient
where year(birthday) - 3 = (
  select year(min(birthday))
  from patient
)
```

Comment: I need to get the patients that are 3 years older than the youngest patient.

Comment: This is what this code does: returns the rows that have 3 years difference than the youngest birthday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the oldest birthdate and then date comparisons.  This looks like:

```
select p.*
from patient as p,
     (select max(birthday) as max_birthday
      from patient
     ) as m
where p.birthday <= dateadd("yyyy", -3, m.max_birthday) and
      p.birthday > dateadd("yyyy", -4, m.max_birthday);
```

Note that this is precisely 3 years, based on the day of the your